# SQL Calculation Query

Tags: mysql, subquery, view

```
SELECT
    (SELECT sum(cost) from cost_table) AS "amount_paid"
FROM member_management;
```

I need the value that has been calculated by the sub-query, to be used in
next column for further calculation. Example given below:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT sum(cost) from cost_table) AS "amount_paid",
    amount_paid/5 AS "share price"
FROM member_management;
```

Comment: I think you can figure this one out

Comment: A suggestion, please use a title like "SQL calculation query" which suggests the topic you need help on, and write the question as part of your question text along with the code

Comment: will keep that in mind

i am new to this
thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse an alias in the same `select` clause you define it. One way to solve this would be do the calculation

```
SELECT m.*, amount_paid, share_price 
FROM member_management m
cross join 
(
    SELECT sum(cost) as amount_paid, sum(cost) / 5 as share_price 
    from cost_table
) tmp
```

Comment: This is the actual query.

the code between stars need to be converted in the format

i tried your solution but maybe i am writing it wrong.

can you help with this

thanks [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7036375fecb31b7d6f01004b15898472

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot refer to a column alias in an another expression in the select list, you need to

- either repeat the sliased expression in the 2nd calculation
- or you need to move the subquery from the select list to the from clause

Sample code for the 2nd suggestion:

```
SELECT
    amount_paid",
    amount_paid/5 AS share price
FROM (SELECT sum(cost) as amount_paid from cost_table) t
Join member_management
```

Comment: This is the actual query.

the code between stars need to be converted in the format

i tried your solution but maybe i am writing it wrong.

can you help with this

thanks [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7036375fecb31b7d6f01004b15898472

Comment: Pls edit the question itself and include the relevant code. However, next time pls do this **before** anyone answers because you are wasting our time this way.

Comment: [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5ca7b45d8180c52b9d45186c4e73a6b. It could have been harder for me to understand the concept with big query. sorry for wasting your time, i am new to this. Though i got the solution, its in the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sum(cost) = "amount_paid" and amount_paid/5 = "share price" then you should use sum(cost)/5 = "share price" this way..try this

```
SELECT
(SELECT sum(cost) from cost_table) AS "amount_paid",
(SELECT sum(cost)/5 from cost_table) AS "share price"
FROM member_management;
```

Comment: [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7036375fecb31b7d6f01004b15898472.  This is the actual query. The part between the stars ( **   ** ) needs to be converted. i want to avoid retyping the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

the above used queries are there for just understanding the concept

"file 1" contains the actual query which i was using and "file 2" contains the solution

[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b497f6a379d26532144ac13bd5fde20e